# jQuery does not work on Wordpress but works perfectly in normal html template

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have been working on a website project for over a week now. Finally html template design is completed and today I started to convert it to a WordPress theme. I have enqueue'd the jQuery and my custom jQuery script properly. But WordPress does not seem to recognize my code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
if ( $(window).width() > 900) {

  $(window).scroll(function() {

  parallax();

});


function parallax() {

  var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  $('.section-one-bg').css('background-position', 'center '+
  (wScroll*0.5)+'px')

}
}
else {

}

if ( $(window).width() > 900) {

$(window).scroll(function() {

var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

$('.imac').css({
  'transform' : 'translate(0px, -'+ wScroll /25 +'%)'
});


$('.iphone').css({
  'transform' : 'translate(0px, -'+ wScroll /15 +'%)'
});

$('.surfacebook').css({
  'transform' : 'translate(0px, -'+ wScroll /15 +'%)'
});

$('.macbook').css({
  'transform' : 'translate(0px, -'+ wScroll /7 +'%)'
});

$('.section-one-text').css({
  'transform' : 'translate(0px, '+ wScroll /8 +'%)'
});

$('.section-three-text').css({
  'transform' : 'translate(0px, '+ wScroll /4 +'%)'
});

$('.section-four-text').css({
  'transform' : 'translate(0px, '+ wScroll /8 +'%)'
});

$('.section-five-text').css({
  'transform' : 'translate(0px, '+ wScroll /6 +'%)'
});

$('.home-contact-form').css({
  'transform' : 'translate(0px, -'+ wScroll /30 +'%)'
});

});
}
else {

}

$(window).scroll(function() {

var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if(wScroll > $('.area-box').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {

$('.area-box').each(function(i){

  setTimeout(function(){

    $('.area-box').eq(i).addClass('area-box-show');
  }, 170 * (i+1));
});

}
});
```

Best Regards.

Comment: What is the error you're getting, if any? Can you link to the site?

Comment: If code is being loaded properly ...probably getting `$ not defined` error due to wordpress using `jQuery.noConflict()`. Try wrapping code in an IIFE as per [noConflict() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: This is the error I am getting. "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"

Comment: Hi  JHS, I am using a local server to develop that's why cannot show it. Anyway the issue is resolved now. Thanks for the comment. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the code is being enqueued propery and it is being loaded in page you are probably getting `$ not defined` error due to wordpress using `jQuery.noConflict()`.

Try wrapping your code in an IIFE as per [noConflict() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
(function($){
  /* your code here*/
})(jQuery)
```

This allows you to continue using `$` inside the IIFE

Comment: Thanks charlietfl, your solution worked. Also I found another method that works. "jQuery(document).ready( function($){ content here }" adding all the jQuery functions inside this code also work. Thanks once again charlietfl,  Have a nice day!

Comment: Use your browser console to check for errors. Should have seen that error and could have noted it in question or searched for results in google using that error message